# Switch numpy vectors inside matrix using slicing/indexing

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let us consider the following Matrix:

```
[v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6] = 
[[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]],
```

where the vectors [v2 v3] and [v5 v6] are switched in respect to the identity matrix.

Starting from the identity matrix, how can we build the previous matrix using slicing/indexing?

If one want to do it explicitly, we should do the following:

```
x = np.eye(6)
x[[1,2]] = x[[2,1]]
x[[4,5]] = x[[5,6]]
```

Comment: What is your input? 6 vectors with only a single 1 on each?

Comment: yes, resulting in a 6x6 matrix.

Comment: I dont think you need slicing, indexing for that, given that you have the vectors. I would use np.vstack assuming the vectors are row vectors.

Comment: The reason for slicing is the speed. vstack is much slower when compared with slicing.

Comment: But what are you going to apply slicing on? Anyway what is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: Because the final goal is to have a (3N x 3N) matrix.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is... can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vectored solution extensible to any `N` :

```
N=2
s = np.zeros((3*N,3*N))
pattern = [[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]]
s.reshape(N,3,N,3)[range(N),:,range(N),:] = pattern
```

for

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a function (that I know) that will swap the positions of your columns, as you can do that with basic slicing as you posted. You can always build a function of the sort:

```
def swap(arr, *tups, copy=False):
  ix = np.array(tups)
  if copy:
    arr = arr.copy()
  arr[ix.ravel()] = arr[ix[:,::-1].ravel()]
  return arr

swap(np.eye(6), (0,2), (1,3))
>> array([[0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

If you want performance however I would suggest using sparse matrices. The `csr_matrix` stores nonzero columns in the `indices`, making switching columns easy:

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse
I = sparse.eye(6, format='csr')
I.indices[[0,2,1,3]] = I.indices[[2,0,3,1]] 
print(I.todense())
>> array([[0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```py
# helper function, swaps two rows
def swaprows(arr, row1, row2):
    temp = arr[row1].copy()
    arr[row1] = arr[row2]
    arr[row2] = temp
    return arr

a = np.eye(6)
a = swaprows(a, 1, 2)
a = swaprows(a, 4, 5)
print(a)
# => 
# [[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]]
```

Note that python uses 0-indexing, I guess you are coming from R or Matlab, and your last code block would a) not use double braces and b) you would get an index out of bounds error from trying to index an array of size 6 at the 6th position.

Comment: Is version is slower than the one that I've present and it is not generalized. If you have a 1024x1024 matrix is no longer useful. That is the reason why I explicitly ask for the use of slice/indexing

Comment: By generalized, what do you mean? You didn't provide any information about that. Do you have a list of indices you need to swap somehow? Please be more specific.

Comment: Generalization means that you can have a NxN matrix and the rule must be applied. In slicing language, all second and third vectors should be swaped in a frequency of 3.

Comment: What do you mean by "second and third vectors", and what is "frequency" in this case?